# How to iterate Javascsript Map without forEach?

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, break

How to iterate over javascript `Map` without `forEach` (so I could `break` in the middle, or is there a way to `break` from `forEach`? Couldn't use object since the order is sometimes random on certain browser, where `Map` ordering is as defined.

```
let map = new Map();
map.set(1,'google.com');
// very long list
map.set(12312,/[^a-z]+/);

let match = 'nothing';
for(let z in map) { // doesn't work, but works for object
  if( foo.match(z) ) {
    match = map.get(z); // map[z]; on object
    break;
  }
}
```

the nearest thing i found is using `.keys()`

```
let iter = map.keys();
while(!iter.next().done) {
  if(foo.match(iter.value)) {
    match = map.get(iter.value);
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) provide three iterators:

1. For their entries, which are provided as `[key, value]` arrays. This is the default iterator for the map, and also available via the `entries()` method.
2. For their keys: `keys()`.
3. For their values: `values()`.

Here's an example looping through the entries, destructuring them into `key` and `value` constants:

```
for (const [key, value] of map) {
    // `key` is the key of the entry, `value` is the value
    if (/*...some condition...*/) {
        break;
    }
}
```

*(You don't* have *to destructure, though, you could use `for (const entry of map)` and then use `entry[0]` for the key and `entry[1]` for the value.)*

Or for looping keys:

```
for (const key of map.keys()) {
    // ...
```

Or for looping values:

```
for (const value of map.values()) {
    // ...
```

---

Applying the default iterator to your example code:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set(1,'google.com');
// very long list
map.set(12312,/[^a-z]+/);

let match = 'nothing';
for (const [key, value] of map) {
  if (foo.match(key)) {
    match = value;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: whoa, this is new for me, last javascript I learned is around 12 years ago XD

Comment: @Kokizzu - Heh, a lot has changed since 2015. :-) Coincidentally, I've written a book about those changes, it covers everything added in ES2015 through ES2020 (and a bit of ES2021). Links in my profile if you're interested. Happy coding!